# Sphax texture pack & Feed the Beast

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I tried to use the Sphax texture pack for Feed the Beast, but it caused mobs to display as wireframes and my minimap to break.

Is there something special I need to do to get it to work correctly?

Comment: Does Sphax include FTB support? because some texture packs just don't work once the game has become heavily modded.

Comment: Good choice, Sphax is awesome

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the base Sphax texturepack downloaded, you have to grab [the Sphax for FTB addon from the same site](http://bdcraft.net/patch-details?i=1-Feed+the+Beast). Note that the addon supports Mindcrack, DW20, Lite, Tech World, and Magic World FTB packs, but *not* Ultimate. If you're playing Ultimate, Sphax is not (yet) the texturepack for you.

Comment: That's what I did, but it still broke everything. I'll try again when I get home, I guess.

Comment: @Rev Are you using one of the supported versions of FTB as listed on the page, or are you using FTB Ultimate? If Ultimate, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yea, I'm using direwolf20.